# Locate Folders inside of Folder

Tags: c#, wpf

Goal:
 Locate all folders inside of a specified folder and then retrieve address of folders located inside of specified folder.

For instance if you select the specified folder "v" and then you locate all folders that is totally 8 folders.

Problem:
I don't have the exactly source code for it in order to create it.

Information:
- If I change the specified folder there always gonna be new folders for instance the specified addres can be "v" or "a"

**When I define "address" that is for instance "C:\a\1\11\111".**

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\folder\");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    DateTime createDate = file.CreationTime;
    string extension = file.Extension;
    long size = file.Length;
    string path = file.FullName;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Close-Voting: I have no idea what you're talking about. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting questions in StackOverflow. BTW, if you need stuff done, I can do it *for profit.*

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve or what problem you have.

Comment: I'am doing this for increasing and improving my ability.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use recursion, for example:

```
public static void GetDirectoryTreeRecursively(string _path)
{
    var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(_path);
    foreach (var directory in directories)
    {
        // use path, save to list, etc...
        GetDirectoryTreeRecursively(directory);
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help... however, I think that vesan has provided a better and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't feel like doing recursion, you can also use this:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\folder\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: +1, Recursion like in the other answers (without the use of a trampoline) will eventually blow the stack.